# Identify anonymous class instance in JAVA

Tags: java

I am thinking of a framework which accepts weak references. Having weak reference to an anonymous class instance does not make sense, so I want to warn the user at runtime by an assertion failure.

So, is there a way to identify that the particular class instance is of some anonymous class?

Comment: Besides Petter's answer: Why do you think that it does not make sense having a weak reference to an anonymous class instance? They are very valid objects that have the same lifecycle than any other object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
myObj.getClass().isAnonymousClass();
```